# Loop over a list from xml results in Ansible

Tags: xml, loops, ansible

I have an `xml` response like this:

```
"model": {
    "results": [ {"item": "A", "xml":"...."}, {"item": "B", "xml":"...."} ]
 }
```

I am trying to loop over the list of the results and get the element 'xml'. For now i am doing something like this:

```
- name: Retrieve xml tags 
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ item.string }}"
    xpath: "{{ item.path }}"
    content: text
  loop:  
    - { path: "/rpc-reply/lldp-remote-system-name", string: "{{ model.results[].xml }}" }
```

But this is not working. I have tried also this:

`model.results[*].xml` but is wrong.

And I have tried to add a second loop inside but I am not getting anything. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the list in response like below:

```
  - name: xml tags
    xml:
      xmlstring: "{{ item.xml }}"
      xpath: "/rpc-reply/lldp-remote-system-name"
      content: text
    loop: "{{ model.results }}"
```